# jQuery isotope with scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying implementing Isotope plugin in a fixed width container, but i'm having trouble getting scrollbars to show.

What i want is to force scrollbars(either default or some fancy ones) on Isotope layout, but it needs to be in a fixed width and height environment, with overflow set to hidden on body.

All the examples i have seen using Isotope, Masonry or Wookmark use scrollbars forced on body or html, but for my case it needs to be set to hidden.

Please, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Basically i tried implementing Isotope in a fixed width container, but the problem is that i must have overflow set to hidden on body.

Comment: I tried adding overflow:auto,scroll,custom scrollbars, but none of these force scrollbars on #container which is holder for isotope items.

Comment: Take a look at this example, it reflows nicely-http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/P6JGY/6/  But in my case when resizing it just goes berserk, because i have no scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar problem by this way:

```
var $container = $(".container");
$container.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  itemPositionDataEnabled: true,
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
  masonry: { rowHeight: 107,columnWidth : 413 } }).css('overflow','auto');
```

Comment: the solution is
.css('overflow','auto');

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your scroll bars are not being displayed because overflow was set to hidden inline, thus having higher precedence in CSS. jQuery could solve this by changing the inline css.

To force scroll bars with pure CSS try using the !important keyword to override inline styling.

```
#container {
overflow:auto !important;
}
```